# Why is it running the previous file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

My code is running the previous file(program.cs) instead of my new file (Answer #1.cs)
[I have tried clearing the obj and bin folders but it still keeps running the previous file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZramP.png)

any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Did you make sure you are at the correct path? Copy the folder path where Answer#1.cs is stored and type the command "cd C:/...." then try to execute again

Comment: Try to make changes  into the references... Or try  with: Add New Class....  and copy the content of the file to the new created file...

Comment: A filename cannot contain any of the following characters: `\ / : * ? " < > | # % ;` so you need to Rename the file `Answer #1.cs` to a valid form `Answer1.cs` for example .... and you should check the problems tape it has something ... and when you run your program the entry point will be from `program.cs`

Comment: [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as code and error messages.

Answer (score 2):

It's normal, I've seen your screenshot and your solution **can only have one entry point**.

For your wish to execute Intro(), you should do 2 things:

1. In the former "Program.cs" code, rename the Main into OldMain or something.
2. In the new "Answer #1.cs", rename the Intro into Main (with or without the args arguments; if you omit the args, you won't be able to use them of course).

Notes:

1. You may copy and paste your code into stackoverflow's code editor instead of linking a picture, it's more practical so that users can see the whole thing at once and also copy and paste if needed.
2. Your screenshot shows Visual Studio Code. Certainly, this is why you could have a file with a # in the filename, pointed out by Ibram.
   Why not use Visual Studio Community 2019 or 2022?

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace ConsoleApp1
   {
       class Nananana
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               // The method Main() is the **only** entry point.
               // It tells the system what should be run.
               // Thus, you can't have two Main() methods or
               // want to run the program with a method not called "Main()"

               Console.WriteLine("Houououououi");
               Console.ReadKey();
           }
       }
   }
   ```